# mysql: compare value from same column with other values

Tags: mysql

I can't get proper title for the ask, but I will try to explain my question very well.

Table sells(This has record for items say beer, pizza, etc sold by each restaurant at particular price)

```
restaurantID | item_name | price
----------------------------------
1              beer1        4 
1              beer2        5
2              beer1        7
2              beer2        6
```

Constraint:
for any two items say A and B, item A should be sold at value lower than value B or greater than value of B in all restaurant. We can not have a situation where in particular restaurant item A is cheaper than item B compared to all other restaurants.

In above example, beer1 is sold costly than beer 2 in restaurant 2, where as same is sold cheaper in restaurant 1.

My question is, How can we write a query to validate this constraint on a table like above. In this situation we should get 'False' return value as table is violating constraint.

Comment: They wouldn't sell item_names.They would sell item_ids. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the anti-capitalist criteria is that restaurant 1 is cheapest:

You can validate the contents of the table with:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*  
FROM sells A
JOIN sells B
  ON A.item_name=B.item_name
WHERE
  A.price < B.price AND
  A.restaurant_ID != 1
```

This select all the items where restaurant 1 is not the cheapest.

You can't easily write a table constraint. However when inserting a new product we can ensure that it only gets inserted if cheapist:

So for inserting a restaurant 1 item:

```
INSERT INTO sells
SELECT 1,"beer3",8
FROM sells A
LEFT JOIN sells B
  ON A.item_name=B.item_name AND
  B.item_name = "beer3" AND
  B.price < 8 AND
  B.restaurant_ID != 1
WHERE
  B.restaurant_ID IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Inserting a restaurant_ID != 1 item would reverse the criteria.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to check it for all available restaurant in my sells. That is where I find it difficult